# Create external list without link to the item

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, hyperlink

I've got an External Item List (from a SQL Database source) and it works OK.

However, it doesn't seem to matter what I do, I cannot remove the "link to item" from the first column.

I'd like the list to JUST be a list - i.e. users are not able to browse the actual item as it's for lookup purposes.

However, I cannot remove the link.

I've tried to de-select the options on the xsltlistview web part to - but they just re-appear!

---

If it matters, this is based on a stored proc and not the table directly. The list doesn't have a link?

[image]

Comment: Running into the same exact problem, any solutions yet?

Comment: No, I ended up writing a json webservice to return the data and then jQuery/ajax to call it and handle the row being clicked on.  Basically, I avoided anything to do with SharePoint wherever possible as I found that every step I took forward was met with 10 backwards.  I'm sure SP does have a place...but I have not found it yet and we are re-developing our workflow application to use standard .Net MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can have to modify the list view settings. Go to list settings > Views > All Items (if thats your default view).

Uncheck the Title Column(link to item) and select "Title" column without the link to item option. It will work. Refer to the screenshot 
[image]

Comment: Please see my edit above...I don't have that link?

Comment: Is this is a designer based read list you have created or through server object model code ?

Comment: Designer based - Added SecureStore/BDC etc.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check now with ECT but don't you see in Sharepoint Designer 2010 upon pressing "Add/Remove/Columns" (having chosen Web Part there) 4 fields for Title or any linked field:

- Title (linked to item with edit menu)
- Title
- - Title (linked to item)

?

[image]